# How to keep track of items with two values?

Tags: python, dataset

I am newbie to programming, so please bear with my question.

I often need to process data that has two or more components, for example name and age.

```
Alice 32
Bob 42
Terry 23
```

I typically creates two lists name_list and age_list and make sure that the index number fits, so that name_list[2] (Terry) and age_list[2] (23) concerns the same person.

But I kind of have a feeling that this is not very smart once you have bigger amounts of data that you're adding and removing from the lists, as you have no way of knowing if data gets out of sync in case you make a mistake and only delete bob from name_list but not his age from the age_list.

Is there a better way to handle data set like these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. The easy way to save two or more items is a dictionary.

A dictionary has a key an a value, so following your example, you could build the dictonary like this:

```
age = dict() # or {}
age['Terry'] = 23
age['Bob'] = 42
age['Alice'] = 32
print age
{'Terry': 23, 'Bob': 42, 'Alice': 32}
```

You should be familiar with python dictionarys, so you could check [this](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/how-to-use-dictionaries-in-python) link.

If, for example, you want to save the address, the phone number, etc. You could use a [class](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) instead.